# Inverted Controls when doing horizontal collisions in gamemaker studio 2

Tags: collision, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

SO like i tried to do horizontal collisions and the keys keep getting inverted

// step event

```
> **# `
>  `if left key pressed`
   if dleft = true
> > # {
> x += 2;
> `collsion left`
> if place_meeting(x + 12,y,Ground)
> > # {
> x += 3
> > # }
> 
> 
> > # }
> `if right key pressed`
> if dright = true
> > # {
> x -= 2;
> `collision right`
> if place_meeting(x + 12,y,Ground)
> > # {
> x -= 3;
> > # }
> 
> 
> > # }**
> 
> > `
```

I'm not a proffesional gml programer by the way

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do `x += 2` when pressing left. Which means you increase the x-axis by 2 pixels, turning your object to the right. Similairly, decreasing the x-axis will turn you to the left.

For the y-axis however, the reverse is true, increasing it will make you go down, and decreasing it will make you go up. I think that's where the confusion went.

In GMS2 (and probably most game engines) the center point is on the top-left, and by increasing both x and y, you're filling up the space by going to bottom-right. Think of it like reading a book, where you start at top-left.

See bottom example of how it should look like. I've also fixed some formatting to make it more readable:

```
//if left key pressed
if dleft = true
{
    x -= 2;
    //collision left
    if place_meeting(x - 12,y,Ground)
    {
        x -= 3
    }
}
//if right key pressed
if dright = true
{
    x += 2;
    //collision right
    if place_meeting(x + 12,y,Ground)
    {
        x += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your method but it failed

Comment: oh wait i forgot to like set it to top left

Comment: it still didnt work

Comment: heres the code to fix it

Comment: if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_left)
{
 dleft = false
 dright = true
}

if keyboard_check(vk_nokey)
{
 dleft = false
 dright = false
 hspeed = 0;
}
//if left key pressed
if dleft = true
{
    x -= 2;
    //collision left
    if place_meeting(x - 12,y,Ground)
    {
        x -= 3
    }
}
//if right key pressed
if dright = true
{
    x += 2;
    //collision right
    if place_meeting(x + 12,y,Ground)
    {
        x += 3;
    }
}

Comment: I see, you're using `keyboard_check_pressed` for movement. However, `keyboard_check_pressed` means you press and release a button, where `keyboard_check()` will check if the button is only held down. To make it yourself easier, I think you can replace the `if dleft = true` with `if keyboard_check(vk_left)`, and it'll probably do the same thing. without the need to use `dleft` or `dright` booleans.